# Proving $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nz^{n} = \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$ for $z \in (-1, 1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I do not know where to start, any hints are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\dfrac z{(1-z)^2}$? ... We have no idea what your background is or what you know.

Comment: Try differentiating a geometric series. What do you notice?

Comment: @TedShifrin I am currently doing tasks on differentiability and differential equations.

Comment: @Crostul this is indeed a more general expression, however one wont find it by looking for any part of the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac{1}{1-z} \tag 1$$

for $|z|<1$.

Differentiating $(1)$ and multiplying by $z$ (this is legitimate since for any $r<1$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}$ converges uniformly for $|z|\le r<1$) yields

$$\begin{align}
z \frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nz^n\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^n\\\\
&=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}
\end{align}$$

for $|z|<1$.

Comment: Hello!! Could you explain to  me the part you wrote in the parenthesis? Why do we need the uniform convergence?

Comment: @MaryStar Hi.  Yes.  In general, interchanging the order of differentiation and series summation is illegitimate.  However, if the series converges uniformly, then this interchange is permitted.

Comment: Ahh I got it!! Thank you very much for the clarification!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

Without differentiation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1} = 1+2z+3z^2+\cdots \tag 1$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n} = z+2z^2+3z^3+\cdots \tag 2$$

Subtract (2) from (1)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}(1-z) = 1+z+z^2+\cdots$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n}= \frac{z}{(1-z)^2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Another way:
$$S(z)=z+2z^2+3z^3+4z^4+\cdots\Rightarrow $$ $$zS(z)=z^2+2z^3+3z^4+4z^5+\cdots\Rightarrow$$ $$\Rightarrow S(z)-zS(z)=S(z)(1-z)=z+z^2+z^3+\cdots=-1+(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots)$$ $$=-1+\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{z}{1-z}\Rightarrow S(z)=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}nz^n=\frac{z}{(1-z)^2}\quad (|z|<1).$$

EDIT: I didn't see Zaid Alyafeai answer.

Comment: No problem (+1).

Comment: No prolem (+1 also).